# write a regular expression in bourne shell script

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep, sh

I am writing a script which will accept a user parameters only of a certain format.
Something like
MSK16PCF1_SOURCE

i.e. exactly 3 Alpha chars, followed by 2 or 3 digits, followed by 3 or 4 Alphanumeric, followed by _, followed by some alpha chars.

I have written regex as below.

```
^[[:alpha:]]{2}[A-Z][[:digit:]]{2,3}[0,9][[:alnum:]]{2}[A-Z]?\_[[:alpha:]]*
```

but it is not working.
Can you suggested what needs to be changed.

```
$ cat swf.sh

vari=MSK16PCF1_SOURCE
if echo "$vari" | grep -q '^[[:alpha:]]{2}[A-Z][[:digit:]]{2,3}[0,9][[:alnum:]]{2}[A-Z]?_[[:alpha:]]*'; then
     echo success
fi
```

Comment: Where/how are you trying to use that regex?

Comment: Below is the script swf.sh
#########################
vari=MSK16PCF1_SOURCE
if echo "$vari" | grep -q '^[[:alpha:]]{2}[A-Z][[:digit:]]{2,3}[0,9][[:alnum:]]{2}[A-Z]?_[[:alpha:]]*'; then
    echo success
fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should satisfy all your needs.

```
^[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digit:]]{2,3}[[:alnum:]]{3,4}_[[:alpha:]]*$
```

In Basic grep, you need to escape the curly braces inorder to mean curly braces as a repitation quantifier.

```
^[[:alpha:]]\{3\}[[:digit:]]\{2,3\}[[:alnum:]]\{3,4\}_[[:alpha:]]*$
```